# How to register Point clouds using HandEye calibration

Tags: robot, point-clouds

I have built a fringe projection based 3D-Scanner with a projector and camera each. I intend to mount this system on an industrial robot and use it for automatic scanning of components. I know that HandEye calibration needs to be performed to find transformation between Camera co-ord system to Robot base co-ord system. Now, I want to use this information to register point clouds.

To make it more clear:

At position A, I capture PCD1, then I move to position B and capture PCD2. A and B are in Robot co-ord system but I can convert them into Sensor Co-ordinate system using the HandEye calibration data. So, the Sensor was at A’ and B’. Using this information, I want to roughly register PCD1 and PCD2.

Can any one suggest ways to achieve this or refer to any relevant publication?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this thesis:

http://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/800632/800632.pdf

And this library:

http://pointclouds.org/

Comment: I have already attempted feature based registration methods from PCL library but the registration process either fails/time consuming for "certain" components. 
I'm looking for methods which exploit position data of robot to register point clouds. I gave a quick glance at Rusu's thesis but didn't find what I was looking for.I will go through it again.